# find all functions which tangent divides area by half

Tags: real-analysis

Find all positive, nondecresing and convex functions, such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ tangent line in point $(x, f(x))$ divides by half the area of set $\left\{ (t,y) : -\infty < t < x, 0 < y < f(x) \right\}$.

I found out that it is enough to solve such equation $\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt = \frac{1}{2} \frac{f^2(x)}{f'(x)}$

where right hand side is area of a triangle. But I cannot finish the task from here, so I'm writing for help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: differentation of $\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt = \frac{1}{2} \frac{f^2(x)}{f'(x)}$ gives

$f'(x)^2=f(x)f''(x)$.

Observe: $\frac{d}{dx}(\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt)=f(x)$

Comment: I see. So this leads to the equation $f'(x) = f(x)$, which means that $f(x) = ae^{bx}$, right?